# Fedora 29 getting stuck at "Started GNOME Display Manager"

Tags: fedora

This has been happening for a while now about a month. I thought it would be fix with new updates but it didn't.

The file /var/log/Xorg.0.log.old has this last few lines before the crash

```
[574.086] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Deleting GPU-0
[574.087] (WW) xf86CloseConsole: KDSETMODE failed: Input/output error
[574.087] (WW) xf86CloseConsole: VT_GETMODE failed: Input/output error
[574.087] (WW) xf86CloseConsole: VT_ACTIVATE failed: Input/output error
[574.088] (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

I tried opening up the virtual terminal but won't let me type (It's stuck)
So how can I fix it?

Comment: Check to see if a file `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` was written at the time it failed. If so, then it may contain useful information. But be aware that the file may be from a previous boot and only indicate success, so check its timestamp. Such a file from the successful boot would not be useful.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Sorry man... it gets changed after the successful boot from 4.19

Comment: Then try the unsuccessful boot, and see if the file is changed.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I did the unsuccessful boot first and then restarted for the successful boot to check the file. But the file has the success boot time. What else can I do?

Comment: In that case the file might be renamed to `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The file has these last lines

Comment: That's not really readable. Please post the relevant lines in your question, and link to the entire file pasted at a pastebin site such as fpaste.org. You can use the `fpaste` command on your Fedora machine to upload the file to the pastebin.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Sorry man. I'm new at this. I have edited the question. Can you please look at it?

Comment: That's still not enough. We need the complete file, or at least much more of it. Please use `fpaste` to upload it, as you were previously advised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also stuck at the `started GNOME display manager...` today.

However, I solved my own problem by removing `gdm` and installing `lightdm`, which give me a good look in the start session. I've also re-install the nvidia driver but I can not tell which part really help (Maybe both of them).

Here is the command line I used to solve it...

PS: I also add `nouveau.modeset=0` in /boot/grub2/grub.cfg  but it gives no luck (but better resolution)

```
dnf remove gdm-1:3.30.1-2.fc29.x86_64 
dnf -y install lightdm-gtk
dnf -y remove nvidia-*
sudo dnf -y install akmod-nvidia xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-cuda xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-libs
sudo systemctl enable lightdm
```

You may check by start the lightdm immediately

```
systemctl stop gdm
systemctl start lightdm
```

Now I am totally fine without re-install the whole system as I did last time.

Comment: I solved the problem by installing windows.Didn't want to but I had no choice

Comment: You can study what gnome display manager and lightdm is, and then you will know why this can be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Tried changing quiet to noquiet and nouveau.modset=0 in grub and it actually fixed it

Comment: modset or modeset?

Answer (score 0):

This may be an unrelated fix, but I had the exact same symptoms of GDM apparently hanging in a started state, when in fact it was X11 that had failed to start. This does not always get logged properly in `dmesg` or `/var/log/boot.log`, so it's an easy thing to miss.

If you are able to get to a tty, verify that Xorg started up properly by checking `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`

If Xorg failed for any reason, your best bet is to follow the errors to a resolution. In my case, I had installed nvidia with my native package manager (dnf), then later manually installed compiled drivers without uninstalling the old ones. This resulted in two duplicate `nvidia.conf` files appearing in my `/etc/X11` configs, which caused a conflict and X server could not start.

Simply deleting the redundant conf file and running `startx` solved my issue. Your mileage may vary. In many cases, deleting the existing xorg.conf and allowing xorg to regenerate the file by itself via `startx` is all it needs.

For all that Xorg is, it does a really good job of configuring/fixing itself. :)